# how to add array of objects into existing object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `object`, I want to push an `array` of `object` into it so that it must look like this

What i'm trying to push is skills `object`  `skills = {"css":true,"javascript":true}`

**I want something like below object**

```
alldata = {"companyName":"abc","jobRole":"permanent",skills:[{"css":true,"javascript":true}]};
```

I'm trying something like this

```js
var details = {
  companyName: "", 
  jobRole: "", 
  startDate: "2017-09-19T09:59:06.479Z", 
  endDate: "2017-09-19T09:59:06.479Z", 
  html: "html"
};
 
var skills = {
  html: "html", 
  css: "css", 
  javascript: "javascript", 
  php: "php", 
  laravel: ""
};

const allData = Object.assign({}, details, skills);
console.log(allData);
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to push `skills` into an array, as an array item with 1 item, with 1 object literal inside doesn't really make sense.  Or are you after a property called skills that's an array like ['html','css','javascript'] etc.

Comment: Do you need the boolean as values?{"css":true ...} etc?what are these booleans based on?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an empty object provide an object with `skills` property as the first argument, where add `skills` object(or its clone in case you don't want to keep the reference to the original object) as the first element.

```js
var details = {companyName: "", jobRole: "", startDate: "2017-09-19T09:59:06.479Z", endDate: "2017-09-19T09:59:06.479Z", html: "html"};
var skills = {html: "html", css: "css", javascript: "javascript", php: "php", laravel: ""};




const allData = Object.assign({ skills: [skills] }, details);

// or in case you don't want to keep reference to main object
const allData1 = Object.assign({ skills: [Object.assign({},skills)]}, details);


console.log(allData);
console.log(allData1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```js
var details = {companyName: "", jobRole: "", startDate: "2017-09-19T09:59:06.479Z", endDate: "2017-09-19T09:59:06.479Z", html: "html"};


var skills = {html: "html", css: "css", javascript: "javascript", php: "php", laravel: ""};



  const allData = Object.assign({}, details, {skills : [skills]});
  
  console.log(allData);
```

```
{skills : [skills]}
```

inside Object.assign() would create the field skills and add to it the value in an array

Answer (score 0):

you can do following code.

```
    var details = {companyName: "", jobRole: "", startDate: "2017-09-
    19T09:59:06.479Z", endDate: "2017-09-19T09:59:06.479Z", html: 
    "html",skills:[]};

    var skills = {html: "html", css: "css", javascript: "javascript", 
    php:"php", laravel: ""};

    details["skills"].push(skills);

    console.log(details);
```